# Resize smallfile tablespace - ORA-01144

Tags: oracle

I have only 2% free on tablespace UNDOTBS1.
It consist from 2 datafiles.

When I launch

```
alter database datafile '+DATADF/dbname/datafile/undotbs1.555.23454732' resize 32G;
```

I got :

> ORA-01144: File size (4194304 blocks) exceeds maximum of 4194303 blocks

---

How can I extend this tablespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the filesystem mount options and `32000M` (not `32000K`).

The first has nothing to do with this.

`32000M` is also not the maximum size, and such file sizes come from the lack of understanding physical database limits: [Physical Database Limits](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/refrn/physical-database-limits.html)

A smallfile tablespace datafile can contain `2^22-1 * database block size` bytes.
With the default 8192 byte block size, that means `4194303 * 8192 = 34359730176` bytes, while `32G = 34359738368` bytes.

So this should work with the standard 8192 byte blocksize in a smallfile tablespace:

```
alter database datafile '+DATADF/dbname/datafile/undotbs1.555.23454732' resize 34359730176;
```

If you reach that limit, you can add the next datafile to the tablespace, example:

```
alter tablespace undotbs1 add datafile `+DATADF` size 100M autoextend on next 100m maxsize unlimited;
```

Where unlimited also means the `2^22-1 * database block size` limit.

Comment: I have two datafiles like this one - '+DATADF/dbname/datafile/undotbs1.555.23454732'

I don't know what was the logic of adding numbers to this files, but can I add new file for example like this - '+DATADF/dbname/datafile/undotbs1_file3' ?
And how without .dbf extension? Can I do it with working database?

Comment: The numbers are added automatically by ASM. Sure you can add a file like that but I would not do that. That will create an alias with that points to an automatically named file (like the ones you alread have) in the background. Just use `alter tablespace undotbs1 add datafile '+DATADF'...` as I already said.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Your current limit with smallfiles is 2G.  As you can see there the limit is 4194303 blocks, which is 4194303 x 512 byte block size = 2,147,483,136 bytes = 2G.

> Option 1:

Mount your file systems with the -largefiles option, which will allow you to create 32G and higher.

> Option 2:

You can only add 2G datafiles.

```
alter tablespace UNDOTBS1 add datafile 'path/filename' size 2G;
```

The -largefiles option has been the default for many years now, so there shouldn't be a problem for your unix admin to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that, for some strange reason in Oracle's internal space calculations, "**32G**" just doesn't work here.

"**32000K**" will work perfectly well, although it may be a *tiny* bit smaller than you'd like.

Alternatively, just add a third Data File of whatever size you like.